# Manage heap size

Tags: android, heap-memory

I am loading images from database in may android app using bitmap.Since my app contains lot of images I am getting out of memory error. I have also given the permission android:largeHeap="true" in manifest file. I have also used system.gc() but nothing solve my purpose.The heap size gets increased as my app proceeds. How can I manage my heap size? I have also scaled the image when I am using bitmap.

Comment: just use this for image loading http://square.github.io/picasso/ and store only physical path to datbase

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" is gud option, if you want to u can use resize,lazylist for displaying images in listview

Comment: You dont have unlimented memory, maybe you should look for a different approach, like loading tiles...

Comment: You can't rely in `System.gc()`. Actually this call does not fire the garbage collection. Instead of that, it says to android that it would runs the garbage collector, but you haven't any assurance about what time it will happen.

Comment: are you doing the download with an async task?

Comment: @erik-No i m not using async task

Answer (score 1):

You are testing your app on emulator or device??? Try to test it on device. Another thing is use lazy loading & same time you can use clearing cache to decrease memory load.

Comment: @user3811114-I have also tested it on device and I am getting this error there also.

Comment: Why don't you go for lazy loading (listview). If you want to apply it so I can share you some good links. It'll solve your problem of memory load.

Comment: @user3811114- I am displaying images in grid view not in list view.U can share ur links I will give them a try.

Comment: Actually listview & gridview are almost same concepts. You just have to make few changes in your code if you use gridview instead of listview. Sending you links for your reference.                    http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134                                           http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/lazy-loading-image-download-from.html